# how to retain original file name when using imagemagick conversion

Tags: linux, command-line, conversion, imagemagick

## background

I like to take screenshots from apps, and put a lot of care in *naming* them ie

```
 onboarding01.png
 onboarding02.png
 dashboard01.png 
 dashboard02.png
 ..
```

I run these images by [imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org) on command line to auto convert them.

## problem

According to the [docs](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php), I can write something like this to convert all those files

```
convert '*.png' - resize 120x120 thumbnail%03d.png
```

the problem is that this conversion will simply rename all those files into something like

```
thumbnail01.png
thumbnail02.png
thumbnail03.png
..
```

I want the original file names to appear.. something like this

```
 onboarding01_shrunk.png
 onboarding02_shrunk.png
 dashboard01_shrunk.png 
 dashboard02_shrunk.png
 ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was amost offensively simple:

```
ls | xargs -I % convert % -resize 432x768 shrunk_%
```

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13760038/766570) answer